# Code completion for OGNL in Thymeleaf views (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, thymeleaf

I'm using Eclipse with the Thymeleaf plugin (https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin). It gives me code completion on the th attributes:

`<div th:....`

However, what I really need is code completion on the 'OGNL' expressions which go inside these attributes, like this:

`<div th:text="${my.object.....}">`

Is there a way to enable code completion on these expressions?